# how to test js files which exported with export default?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a simple JavaScript file like this:

```
// sum.js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
export default { sum };
```

and I want to test that file with jest in same folder like this:

```
// sum.test.js
const { sum } = require('./sum')

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

test fails that way however everything works perfect if I export as `module.exports = sum;`instead `export default { sum };` but I'm not allowed to change original js file so I could only change test file. How can I complete my test succesfully with that situation?

Solutions I've tried (but failed are below)

- `const { sum } = require('./sum').default`
- `const { sum } = require('./sum').default()`
- `import { sum } from './sum'`

Comment: I tried installing `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` and using `const { sum } = require('./sum').default` worked for me for some reason. Perhaps your transform configuration is messing something up somewhere, you can log the result of `require('./sum')` to see what happens, it might give you an idea

Comment: I've installed plugin and used `.default` but it still throwed me same error @CertainPerformance https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nyHtdF6GcT/

Comment: Check out https://github.com/CertainPerformance/jestrequire-problems if you're curious, I just made it to demonstrate. It's extremely bare-bones, `npm install` then `npm test` runs without problems. Make sure to have `"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"` inside `.babelrc` as a test plugin

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty weird to have a default export be an object with a single property, because it means that accessing the value there will take *at least* two lines. First use `import` without brackets to get to the object, then extract the property from it:

```
import sumObj from './sum';
const { sum } = sumObj;
```

It looks a bit ugly. Ideally you'd want to change the `sum.js` file to either have named exports - eg, have `sum` be a named export, so it can then be imported easily:

```
export function sum(a, b) {
```

```
import { sum } from './sum';
```

(but, if you can't change the original file, that's unfortunate)

Comment: probably offtop, but do you have any ideas why `const { sum } = require('./sum').default` may not work here? to me looks equal to "explicit default import + destructuring". am checking https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4742 if that answers this